# Get JSON/String of through2 stream?

Tags: node.js, gulp, through2

I have a bunch of zip files, each file contains a .config file.

I want to iterate each zip, unzip it, read the config file, and use that config file to upload the zip file somewhere.

```
gulp.task('deploy-zips', function () {
  const filter = config()[target].filter;

  return gulp.src([destination + '/' + filter])
    .pipe(deployZips());
});
```

This is the task entry point.

```
function deployZips() {
  return through({ objectMode: true }, function (zipFile, zipEncoding, zipCallback) {
    gutil.log(zipFile.path.split('\\').reverse()[0]);

    gulp.src(zipFile.path)
      .pipe(unzip({
        filter : function(entry){

          if (entry.type !== 'File') {
            return false;
          }

          return entry.path.indexOf('deploy-config.json') > -1;
        }
      }))
      .pipe(through({ objectMode: true }, function(configFile, configEncoding, uploadCallback){
          gutil.log(configFile.path); // Outputs the file name as deploy-config.json

          //????
          var config = JSON.parse(configFile);

          uploadCallback(null, configFile);
      }))
      .on('end', function() {
          zipCallback(null, zipCallback);
      })
      ;
  });

}
```

This seems to display all the zip files I'm after, and then it outputs the config file I want to look at. However at this point I'm baffled as to how I can parse the config file to get the config.

I've tried parsing the configFile, reading the file using `fs.readFileSync(...)`

But nothing seems to work. The config contains the credentials to upload to, so I need to read it and then use that to send it to S3 or where ever its configured for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `configFile` to `configFile.contents`

> var config = JSON.parse(configFile.contents);

See https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#file

```
function deployZips() {
  return through({ objectMode: true }, function (zipFile, zipEncoding, zipCallback) {
    gutil.log(zipFile.path.split('\\').reverse()[0]);

    gulp.src(zipFile.path)
      .pipe(unzip({
        filter : function(entry){

          if (entry.type !== 'File') {
            return false;
          }

          return entry.path.indexOf('deploy-config.json') > -1;
        }
      }))
      .pipe(through({ objectMode: true }, function(configFile, configEncoding, uploadCallback){
          gutil.log(configFile.path); // Outputs the file name as deploy-config.json

          var config = JSON.parse(configFile.contents);

          uploadCallback(null, configFile);
      }))
      .on('end', function() {
          zipCallback(null, zipCallback);
      })
      ;
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kilianc - the missing piece was `.contents` everything works perfectly now :D